# Online API for image processing

Tags: web-apps, api, web-apis

I'm looking for a REST API website that can process image files (like photosohop or imagemagick) that can be uploaded via curl and returns the url to the processed image.

For example, resize image, apply image filters, etc...

*Free/gratis*

Comment: Could you please give a few examples of particular operations that you want to perform?

Comment: Also, please state your budget and the max volume of requests per day (10? 1 million?)